# Basic java import question

Tags: java, import

I need to import "import java.awt.Rectangle. I import it and it tells me the import cannot be resolved. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class RectangleCalculator {

    import java.awt.Rectangle
```

Comment: And I have to import `java.util.List`. But what's the question?

Comment: You should ask a concrete question. If you don't know the basic syntax of Java, you should read some book or do the getting started tutorial.

Comment: Did you try "import import java.awt.Rectangle" instead of "import java.awt.Rectangle"?

Comment: It's not showing my full question.... I don't know why.

Comment: -1 for not even reading a tutorial where the first thing is the explanation on where an import statement needs to be written

Comment: You can still edit your question...

Comment: I keep editing it.. but nothing changes.. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 17):

Turn this

```
public class RectangleCalculator {

    import java.awt.Rectangle
```

into this

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class RectangleCalculator {
```

Consider what happens when you define an int inside your class:

```
public class Foo {
    int theFoo;
```

The compiler says "Oh, I have a new variable, called `theFoo`, of type `int`! I had better resolve `int`!" Well, when you put the import statement inside, it reads it like that and says "Oh, I have a new variable, called `java.awt.Rectangle`, of type `import`! I had better resolve `import`... wait, I can't resolve `import` :-("

And your compiler gets sad.

Comment: Another +1 for the same reason

Answer (score 3):

I would say put the

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
```

under the package line of the file you need it in

Comment: imports are still statements, and must be terminated by a semi-colon to separate them from the next statement.

Answer (score 3):

write:

```
import java.awt.Rectanglе;
public class RectangleCalculator {
```

Answer (score 2):

Imports can only be declared in the "Compilation Unit" scope, they cannot be declared in the "Class Scope".

Move that import outside of the class, and everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the import at the top of the file, below the package declaration (which you probably have, no?).

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
```

Don't miss the `;` at the end!

Answer (score 1):

Here, read this.  It will give you a general overview of packages and imports.  It will help you learn the structure of a java source file.  Your structure is wrong.

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html

EDIT:
Try this one too.  It is a little more "involved", but has a lot of good details:

http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter05/packagesImport.html

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your .java file just write

```
import java.awt.Rectangle
```